# How to get backup from from a very populated table using SQLDEVELOPER

Tags: oracle, backup, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table containing more than 6,000,000 records. When I use the export feature of SQLDEVLPER to get backup, SQLDEVELOPER generates a sql files as big as 8GB which I cannot open it in the SQLDEVELOPER or Notepad or ... because it makes the memory full!
Please guide me know how I can divide it to smaller parts?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Forget notepad for anything but the most basic editing on small files.  You should look into a file viewer/editor that is designed for large files.  For viewing very large files, I've had great success with the [V File Viewer](http://fileviewer.com/) .  For editing, I often use [Textpad](http://textpad.com/), but I don't usually open a file this big for editing, just viewing.

It also begs the question WHY you are opening the entire file, as you can just do a "more" on the file (or "less" in linux) to have a peek (check format maybe).  It should also be said that a DBA should be doing backups (rman or data pump maybe) of any production data, but anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
It should also be said that a DBA should be doing backups (rman or data pump maybe) of any production data, but anyway.
The reason is that I need the data in the SQL format to be able to insert it in different databases. I am not sure if I can get a SQL back up from tables using rman

Comment: I just checked it with text pad and it wasn't able to open the file either (Showed Disk Full Error)

Comment: You can try [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/large_file_handling.html) which can handle large files because it is really a disk based editor and only loads pieces of the file into memory at a time.  Still, not sure why you need to EDIT this file.

Comment: Thank for your attention. I want to divide it to smaller parts to be able to open it using common editors like notepad

Comment: I sometimes need to split a large file to process the pieces in parallel, but if I'm on Windows I use some custom C# libraries.  You might try searching for a file split utility you like.  I found [JFSplit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jfsplit/) on Sourceforge, which seems to do what you want, but I cannot attest to it as I've not used it before.  Good luck.